# Assigning values to a key in a pointer to a record in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Sorry if the title is a little confusing. What I'm doing is creating a structure such as:

```
struct record
{
    int value;
    int key;
};
```

Then using a typedef to call a pointer to record "Item" like this:

```
typedef struct record* Item;
```

Basically I'm following how it was done in Algoriths in C by Robert Sedgewick (third edition) on page 290 in case anyone happens to have this book.

What I'm having trouble with is reading in a value from the console, then assigning that to the key. Here's what I have, and the errors that I'm getting:

```
void setKey(Item *element, int x)
{
    element->key = x;
}

void standInput(Item A[], int length)
{
    int i;
    int x;
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter a value for spot %i: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &x);
        setKey(A[i], x);
    }
}

gcc Item.h
Item.h:33:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘setKey’
Item.h:23:3: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘setKey’ was here
```

If I could get a nudge in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it. I got the program for this assignment working perfectly when Item was just simple ints, but now I'm trying to use Item->Key and I'm a little lost :) Thanks!

If anyone needs any other portion of the code that I didn't think necessary, I'll post it as soon as I see the request.

Revision: I moved my setKey function above standInput, so the compilation error has gone away. What I am getting though is a segment fault, so I'm still assigning it wrong :)

Comment: +1 for a well-worded, complete question including description of what you tried and error message. *so* refreshing to see

Comment: Are you allocating memory for each Item in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `setKey`'s first argument should be `Item`, not `Item *`, since the `Item` type already *is* a pointer.  You want to pass a pointer to a record, not a pointer to a pointer to a record.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the address of the array element:

```
setKey(&A[i], x);
```

The type of `A[i]` is `Item` and not `Item *` as the `setKey` method expects

**Edit** As pointed out by Wyzard `Item` is already a pointer to a struct so you should change your signature for `setKey` to take an `Item` and not an `Item *` and call it as `setKey(A[i], x)`.

Comment: Hrm, that didn't quite do it, but I'll play around with it and see if I can't get it up and running. I didn't catch the ampersand issue, so thank you for that!

Comment: @user684594: I updated my answer a bit. In order to resolve the segfault you would need to show more code (like which code is calling `standInput`).

Answer (score 3):

`setKey` takes a pointer to an `Item`. `A[i]` is not a pointer to an `Item`, but an actual `Item` object.

To pass it as a pointer do either:

`setKey(A + i, x);`

or

`setKey(&A[i], x);`

Comment: I believe the second method is preferred; its much clearer what is going on.

Comment: `setKey` takes a pointer to an `Item`, but it *shouldn't*.  The `->` in the implementation of `setKey` expects to be dereferencing an `Item` to get a `record`, not dereferencing an `Item*` to get an `Item`.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you Wyzard. I've already +1'd your answer, and can only encourage others to do so as well. This will only fix the compilation issue about the method signature, though he should be getting another error about erroneously using a double pointer, as you point out.